# CKEDITOR - Disable "Select All" or "Ctrl + A"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am wondering if we can disable `Ctrl + A` or `Select All` feature in a browser having `contenteditable=true` with CKEditor?

Here is a configuration that I am using:
http://ckeditor.com/demo#magic-line

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe it is, and even if it was it's pointless as you can still select with the mouse and/or keyboard directly.

Comment: Yes. But this is a requirement and I am looking for a solution that somehow if we are allowed to disable. Although we should be able to edit a content as in a demo.